# Improve performance of a query using row_number() in Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated sql pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Below query uses row_number() and it is introducing a shuffle move when executing the query.

```
SELECT
         f.col1
        ,f.col2
        ,f.col3
        ,f.col4
        ,rowNum=row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY f.col2 ORDER BY f.col4 desc) 
    FROM  #currentData e
        left join dbo.targetTable f on 
        e.col2 =f.col2
```

[image]

#currentData temporary table and targetTable both are distributed on **col2** column.
I have also created indexes on columns that are used in the row_number() -- (col2 asc,col4 desc) but it didn't get rid of the shuffle move.

I have tried creating a covering index to cover all of the columns in the select statement and columns in the row_number but that didn't resolve the issue either.

Both of the tables have index on the join column (col2).

Also made sure statistics are up to date on these 2 tables.

Query takes long time to process due to the shuffle move, is there any other way to improve the below query performance?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What’s the definition of the two tables in the query? I’m particularly interested in data types and distribution keys

Comment: @GregGalloway Below are the definitions of the 2 tables

`CREATE TABLE [targetTable]
(
 [col1] [binary](32) NOT NULL,
 [col2] [binary](32) NOT NULL,
 [col3] [binary](32) NOT NULL,
 [col4] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
 [col5] [smallint] NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
 DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [col2] ),
 CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
GO
`
#currentTable is a temp table is distributed on [col2] column which is of datatype Binary(32) as it is a hash value.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me it obeys the rules of a distribution compatible join https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-distribute#check-query-plans-for-data-movement Maybe you should double check the definition of the temp table? I’m surprised it’s shuffling.

Comment: Right. Both tables are distributed on the join key. The shuffle move is happening on the row_number() window function, if I remove row_number() from the sql it doesn't shuffle. I've tried creating a covering index hoping it will not shuffle but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you try changing to PARTITION BY e.col2?

Comment: Yeah I did try with e.col2 and that took away shuffle move. But the business logic warrants to be partitioned on f.col2.

Comment: what if you partition by e.col2, f.col2 (both of them). Hopeful that will produce the same results but not shuffle.

Comment: @GregGalloway Thanks. I have added the e.col2 and took away the shuffle data movement, got to validate if it follows the business logic but it did improved the performance. Still not sure why there's a shuffle movement when partitioning on  f.col2 only.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this out the hard way.. unfortunately. I haven't got the time to fully understand but i managed to reduce query performance by 90% through removing the ROW_NUMBER function.

to my understanding the ROW_NUMBER introduces the necessity that each node should have all data to be able to calculate the row_number based on the order by clause. And if the order by (or partition) origins from a big table that's a lot of shuffle going on. Because we use row_number just as a primary key generator I was able to get rid of it but i assume this probably happens with rank etc also.

By removing the row_number the query plan actually does what it should do. Joining without data movement.

Interested to see if anyone has a solution or better explanation.

Comment: Well then does row_number perform well only with replicate tables? Would be interesting to know. Also, I have tried replacing the partition key with e.col2 and there was no data movement which baffles me as both the tables are distributed on col2.